# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') How to overcome this problem?

Tags: node.js

Create a script which uses the "forEach" method. png Json is an array of objects with the following sequence:

```
      "uri": ".....",
      "id": "0222 2.PNG",
      "type": "IMG"
    },
```

gets error:
pngJson.png.forEach((element) => {
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

The debugger reads the file correctly until it fails

Here is a code snippet:

```
  let pngMap = new Map();
    let pngJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(staticJson));

    pngJson.png.forEach((element) => {
        pngMap.set(element.id, element.uri);
    });
```

Comment: can you show us staticJSON?

Comment: {
  "data": [
    {
      "uri": "QmNvzUyXezTMorSXTrFnAyBUJrH6K41GsWqeS",
      "id": "f.PNG",
      "type": "10"
    }
 
  ]
}

Comment: it looks like this, a lot of key values, the same archetype

Answer (score 0):

if your Json is

`{ "data": [ { "uri": "QmNvzUyXezTMorSXTrFnAyBUJrH6K41GsWqeS", "id": "f.PNG", "type": "10" } ] }`

shouldn't it be
`pngJson.data.forEach` instead of `pngJson.png.forEach`?...